# JQuery UI tabs crashing in IE7

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tabs, internet-explorer-7

I am trying to fix a problem on the following website http://mvc.whclpreview.com/ToolSelect

When a user clicks on the i on one of the coloured tabs a popup of a set of UI tabs appear.

All is working fine on all browsers but on IE7 the website is crashing the page.

All help appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: its working fine...can you add snapshot and which window you are using xp or window 7

Comment: Hi Sachin, I tested this on a Windows 7 machine running IE tester in IE7 mode, the result is a bad crash. Since you replied to my post I tested it on a Vista machine running IE7 and it works fine. I am assuming my client is viewing it on IE7 on a machine running XP?

Comment: why you are testing in ie tester ?? it always crash..test your code in browser not in tester....do let us knw is there any prblem in browser